# using ajax with javascript to put in database

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to put the infos into my database, for that, this code is in the connexion.jsp which is a page that ask to log with facebook. 
the code is supposed to be called into the Controller which is a file in java, and go into the databse.

So my problem is the fact that the code $.ajax doesn't seems to work. It doesn't give a success or error window.alert with or without function(){}.
I might have missed some information about ajax, but i can't find more info about my error.

```js
            function fbLogin() {
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        // Get and display the user profile data
                        getFbUserData();
                        $.ajax({
                            method: 'post',
                            url: '/hello/facebookconnection',
                            first_name: response.first_name,
                            last_name: response.last_name,
                            email: response.email,
                            success:
                            //success: function(){
                                window.alert('Sent User data!')//;}
                            ,
                            error:
                                window.alert('Error in sending ajax data')
                        });
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'User cancelled';
                    }
                }, {scope: 'email'});
            }
```

Comment: Have you checked the log for errors? I bet you didn't

Comment: Or at least run the stack snippet you included.  It's probably the same error you're getting in your code.

Comment: Also, why have you commented out the `success` attribute but not its content?

Comment: i did, but didn't understand that one warning, which was the cause of my error XD

And Joseph, there's another success just upper

Answer (score 0):

```
 function fbLogin() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    // Get and display the user profile data
                    getFbUserData();
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: '/hello/facebookconnection',
                        first_name: response.first_name,
                        last_name: response.last_name,
                        email: response.email,
                        success:
                        //success: function(){
                            window.alert('Sent User data!')//;}
                        ,
                        error:
                            window.alert('Error in sending ajax data')
                    });
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'User cancelled';
                }
            }, {scope: 'email'});
        }
```

You have a syntax error in front of your else.

Comment: isnt a bracket missing in front of your else?

Comment: You can't see the bracket? O.o

Comment: Nope in front of you else in your code not in the one I corrected there is no }

Comment: oh lol then you meant before my else XD Yeah my bad, bad copy paste from me

Comment: Where is the function loaded in your app or page is it called after the dom finished loading?